# Fl_Tree callback when FL_WHEN_RELEASE

Tags: fltk

The [documentation for Fl_Tree in FLTK 1.3.4](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Tree.html) says:

> The callback() is invoked depending on the value of when()
>
> - FL_WHEN_RELEASE -- callback invoked when left mouse button is released on an item
> - FL_WHEN_CHANGED -- callback invoked when left mouse changes selection state

but I can't get the callback called if the mouse is released and I can't see a difference between both. Any ideas?

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Tree.H>

static void cb_(Fl_Tree*, void*)
{
  printf ("callback\n");
}

int main()
{
  Fl_Double_Window* w = new Fl_Double_Window(325, 325);
  Fl_Tree* o = new Fl_Tree(25, 25, 255, 245);
  o->callback((Fl_Callback*)cb_);
  o->when(FL_WHEN_RELEASE);
  o->add("foo/bar");
  o->add("foo/baz");
  o->end();
  w->show();
  return Fl::run();
}
```

this snippets outputs "callback" on every change, even if FL_WHEN_RELEASE is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded, the distribution, have a look at test/input.cxx and test/tree.cxx.  Both have tests for the different when selections.

WHEN_CHANGED only makes sense on edit boxes, browsers and tables - you can verify the data as it is typed in.  This does not happen with WHEN_RELEASE.  For all other widgets, there is virtually no difference.

**Edit**

In order for release to fire every time, there are one of three options

1. Modify the source FL_Tree.cxx.  Look for FL_Tree::select.  Change alreadySelected to false.
2. If you look at the source, in the same routine, further down, it says

   ```
   #if FLTK_ABI_VERSION >= 10301
   ```

   If the library is built with FLTK_ABI_VERSION set to 10301, it will call the reselect but there is also a whole load of other stuff it will do when this #define is set since it affects all widgets
3. Comment out the #if FLTK_ABI_VERISON and corresponding #endif in FL_Tree::select.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've also tried the test/tree example. So you say that the documentation is wrong here? It clearly says **FL_WHEN_RELEASE -- callback invoked when left mouse button is released on an item**

Comment: They are both correct - it is just the context.  On a tree view, an item cannot be partially selected so both change and release have the same behaviour.  On an editbox, an item can be partially selected so they have different behaviour.

Comment: But on a Fl_Tree it makes indeed a difference if a already selected item is clicked. If another item was previously selected I expect a callback for FL_WHEN_CHANGED (because the selection has changed). But if a already selected item is clicked again I expect a callback for FL_WHEN_RELEASE

Comment: @Andy - I have added options for changing the behaviour

Comment: I've rebuilt the lib with `--with-abiversion=10304` and the result looks promising. Thank you for the tip

Comment: One keypoint is the new method `item_reselect_mode(FL_TREE_SELECTABLE_ALWAYS)` which was introduced with ABI 1.3.1